# PHP: display message if a field in a form isn't filled only after attempt has been made without javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form with some fields...and I only want to display an error message if an attempt to fill the form has been made (i.e. the submit button was hit)

```
if (fields are empty){

$_POST['fields_empty']= "error message";
}
```

doesn't seem to work...i.e. (perhaps not surprisingly) the error message shows before the user even attempts to fill the form...since the form is empty at this point...how can I prevent this behavior (without using javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field like step in the form with value like 2. Then use this:
`if(isset($_POST['step']) && $_POST['step'] == 2 &&empty($_POST['field'])) { error_msg }`

Answer (score 0):

Normally when the fields are empty the form variable doesnt make it through to POST, eg, if you have "username" as a field isset($_POST["username"]) will return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='text' name='username' value='' />
<input type='submit' name='sned' value='Send' />
</form>
```

php :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    //form was submit
    if (empty($_POST['username']))
    {
       //error - do something
    }
    // if you need check only for empty field better to use 
    // if (trim($_POST['username']) === '') {// error}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't make it without hitting the button or using javascript.

Luckily, there is no reason to do it without hitting buttons, so, it's ok to hit some

a code

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {// if no errors - 
    // saving data 
    // ...
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);// and then redirect
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

a template

```
<? if ($err): ?>
  <? foreach($err as $e): ?>
<div class="err"><?=$e?></div>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$form['name']?>">
  <textarea name="comments"><?=$form['comments']?></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```